# how to start multiple disclosure groups already expanded swiftui

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, swift3, disclosuregroup

I have a foreach with a list of strings, Every element will have an expandable view. I want for all of them to start already expanded.
And I also want to collapse/expand them individually.

```
@State myLists = ["list1", "list2", "list3"]

ForEach(myLists, id: \.self){myList in

     DisclosureGroup(myList){

                Text(myList)

     }

}
```

I want all of them to start already expanded, and to collapse them individually.

I ve tried multiple links but most of them do not work unfortuately.

[SwiftUI DisclosureGroup Expand each section individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68636590/swiftui-disclosuregroup-expand-each-section-individually)
-This one works but it start with all of them closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can make another `View` to do that, e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let myLists = ["list1", "list2", "list3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(myLists, id: \.self){ myList in
            ContentView2(text: myList)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    let text: String
    @State private var expanded = true
    
    var body: some View {
        DisclosureGroup(text, isExpanded: $expanded){
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

Note `id: \.self` is not valid for dynamic `@State` you need to use a real `id` of the data otherwise it'll crash when it changes.